# Quit a window by its win_getid() identifier?

Tags: vim-windows, window-management

I use [something](https://github.com/ivanbrennan/zoo) like [zoomwintab](https://github.com/troydm/zoomwintab.vim) to zoom in/out of a single window view, using tabs to simulate the effect.

It exposes a toggle function to zoom in on a single window, and to zoom back out to the orginal layout.

If I'm zoomed in and I `quit` (rather than toggle), I want to return to the original layout, but with that window removed.

To achieve this, I'm recording the unique window id the zoom originated from,

```
let origin_win = win_getid()
" ...zoom in... (elided)
let s:origin_wins[win_getid()] = origin_win
```

and using that to determine which window I need to quit in addition to the current one.

```
augroup Zoo
  au!
  au QuitPre * if s:zoomed_win_only() | call s:quit_origin() | endif
augroup END

func! s:quit_origin() abort
  let og = s:get_origin()

  if s:exists(og)
    let i = win_getid()
    call win_gotoid(og) | quit
    call win_gotoid(i)
  endif
endf
```

I'm very happy with it, but I think it could be improved if there was a way to quit a specific window by its id. That way I could avoid the need to switch to the origin window, quit it, and switch back to the zoomed window I'm about to quit.

Is there a cleaner way I might do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the window number (as opposed to the window ID) and then use `wincmd` to close:

```
let winnr = win_id2win(og)
if winnr > 0
    execute winnr.'wincmd c'
endif
```

Keep in mind this won't work if the window isn't in the current tab page.

Comment: For my use-case, the window is always going to be in a different tab, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Recent vim includes `win_execute()` which works across tabpages.

```
call win_execute(og, 'close')
```

Beware of changes fired by autocmds from the vimhelp:

> The window will temporarily be made the current window, without triggering autocommands.  When executing {command} autocommands will be triggered, this may have unexpected side effects.  Use |:noautocmd| if needed.